# How can i use {useState} inside ComponentDidMount in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, web

```
const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState('black');
class Accelerons extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
}
componentDidMount = () => {
$(window).on('scroll touchmove', function () {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('.about-us').position().top) {
    setBgColor('red');
  }
  
 });
 };
render() {
return (
  <article
    style={{
      backgroundColor: bgColor,
    }}
  >
    <Overlay />
    <Landing landing={DataAccelerons.landing} />
    <AboutUs itemColor={itemColor} accelerons={DataAccelerons} />
    <Participation itemColor={itemColor} accelerons={DataAccelerons} />
    <TeamMembers itemColor={itemColor} accelerons={DataAccelerons} />
    <Results itemColor={itemColor} accelerons={DataAccelerons} />
    <Footer
      accentColor={DataAccelerons.accentColor}
      footerColors={DataAccelerons.footerColors}
    />
  </article>
);
}
}
export default Accelerons;
```

This gives me an error that we can't use react hooks at the starting ,but if I declare them in render it won't be recognized by ComponentDidMount function ReactJS

Comment: You can use hooks only inside function component, in class components you need to use `this.setState` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 2):

You can use hooks such as `useState` only inside functional component whereas `setState` in the lifecycles in Class components. You don't wanna mix two. A typical usage would go something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [myVal, setMyVal] = useState('Hello World');

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{myVal}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Read More](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

If you want to go with lifecycle methods (such as `componentDidMount`), you may consider using [seState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Also, you can't use `setState` inside `render` method as it would trigger an infinite call.

Answer (score 1):

React hook can be used only functional component whereas `componentDidMount` is the life cycle method for class based component.